# WebdriverIO - how to determine if a page load or refresh happened

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, ui-automation, webdriver-io

I am using WebdriverIO with Javascript and Mocha to create a UI test framework. For that, I am trying to capture screenshots every time a page loads or a page refreshes. Could someone please tell me if this is possible to do it using WebdriverIO or otherwise?

Relevant details: The pages are NOT loaded using driver.url() all the time. The launching URL is arrived at using driver.url(), and then on all navigation happen by clicking on a link on a page or performing an action that leads to another page load. Please also note that page load happens on other conditions as well, for example, when a "Save" button is clicked the same page loads again (refreshes). I am trying to capture a screenshot every time a page loads or refreshes irrespective of whatever action that might cause it. And that's why I want to abstract out the process at a global level than calling driver.saveScreenShot() in multiple places all over the codebase.

Comment: You can try `EventFiringWebDriver` for that. It is basically a generic wrapper for other WebDriver classes, sending notifications about certain events. [Example](https://gist.github.com/krmahadevan/1728633).

Comment: @skandigraun, could you please provide an example?

Comment: @naspras Please edit your question with more details. Right now, I could see myself answering "it can't be done", or "it can be done by doing [any number of possibilities]". For instance, you want to take a screenshot after a page loads: trivial, just add the command to take a screenshot after `driver.get(url)` completes. (There are dozens of questions on SO about this.) Same with reloads, if a reload is performed through Selenium. So please detail what scenarios you have in mind: for each scenario specify the event and what initiated it (Selenium, JavaScript on the page, something else?).

Comment: @Louis, I have added the relevant details.

Comment: @naspras Good, but there's one other category of "refresh" I can think of. Sometimes *parts* of a page are going to refresh automatically (because there's JavaScript code that runs at set intervals) or because the user clicked something. These are not "page refresh" in the sense that they do not cause the browser to load an entire new page. Do you need to take screenshots of such occurrences too?

Comment: Great point @Louis. If that is possible, yes!

Comment: @Louis, could you please tell how we can achieve this?